# Is there a JQuery alternative to JQTouch with better Android Support?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, android, jqtouch

Basically looking for a JQuery plugin with better Android browser support than JQTouch.  Or even an alternative Javascript framework with better mobile support.

Comment: Care to explain what you mean by "better"? If you can point out some issues with JQTouch, more people might be able to help :)

Answer (score 5):

You could try [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/index.php).

Comment: +1 Just tried this on an Android phone and all the demos I tried work.

Answer (score 2):

A list of 18 other mobile frameworks with varying levels of complexity and usefulness, you may be able to find one that fits your needs.

http://iphoneized.com/2009/11/18-mobile-frameworks-development-tools-creating-iphone-apps/

Answer (score 1):

This is more a replacement for JQuery than a replacement for JQTouch, but have you looked at http://xuijs.com/? From the home page:

> We hear your words. Why another JavaScript framework?! When development of PhoneGap was under way we noticed slow load times for modern JavaScript frameworks (such as Prototype, MooTools, YUI, Ext and (yes) even jQuery. A big reason why these libraries are so big is because is mostly they contain a great deal of cross browser compatibility code. The mobile space has less browser implementations (so far) and different needs. Thus XUI.

All this in 7.8kb. Not bad. If you have jQuery experience, you'll find xuiji familiar in some ways.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery Mobile, is the top for android/cross-platform mobile app development: http://jquerymobile.com/ 
I ended up going with JQTouch and doing work-arounds for Android because it's templates look slicker to me.

Answer (score 1):

Like Barnabas said above, [xui](http://xuijs.com) is a great alternative. Also, [Uranium](http://uraniumjs.com) (which includes xui in its download) is a neat set of pre-made widgets that requires no javascript knowlegde - just some attributes in your HTML.